# Jquery how to make a DIV element to work like html A HREF link?

Tags: jquery, html

I am wondering how i can make make a background div called `<div id="branding"></div>` which also contains other divs and elements to act like link.

Is there anyway to make a div element act as a link with `target="_blank"` like option.

How i can make that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean do want div tag acts like a?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your only need is to open an url in new window, you need to use window.open

```
$('#branding').click(function(){
  window.open(your_url, '_blank');
});
```

But the best practice is use the `a tag` itself.

`<a href="your_url" target="_blank">...<a>`

Comment: It will work, but it's a bad practice. If you want to make a link, then do a link ! Make a `<a href="..." target="_blank">...</a>` with a `display: block;` and your background.

Comment: Yes, I know. But as the question itself is "How to make a div element to work like html a ref link". :-)

Comment: I have used this javascript and it seems to work like a link but the problem is that all other divs inside the `<div id="branding">ALL OTHER DIVS HERE HAS THE SAME LINK</div` are having the same link. How i can make it work as a link when you click only over `#branding` ?

Comment: @user2987591 Actually, I didn't understand requirement. If there is content inside the `div#branding`, and when clicking on the content it will open the url as the content is nested used the div. Please create a jsfiddle a sample html.

Answer (score 0):

such as said Jithin, will be better use tag a, but if you want use div then try:

script:

```
$(function(){
    $("div").click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("href")){
            if($(this).attr("target") && ($(this).attr("target")!="" || $(this).attr("target")!="_self")){
                var _hwnd = window.open($(this).attr("href"), ($(this).attr("target"), 'random_word');
            }else{
                window.location = $(this).attr("href")
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and HTML

```
<div class="hyperlink" target="_blank" href="host_controller.php/myroute/myparams">click here</a>
```

Comment: May be increment z-index of div#branding.